How to hide a specific column in AG-Grid on a condition
I'm Using Ag-Grid Enterprise in a .NET Project. I want to hide a column if user changes the  visibility filter of that column. Its hide/show.
Currently I'm Doing this :
kpiData.forEach(function (kpi) {
                    var column = gridOptions.api.getColumn(kpi.name);
                    if (!kpi.Visible) {
                        // Hide the column
                        column.setActualWidth(0);
                        gridOptions.api.setColumnVisible(kpi.name, false);
                    }
                })

The issue is its hiding the column from grid, but it's still visible a bit, and it's draggable, so user can just drag it and make it visible on grid. I want to completely hide it.
There is a hidden column between NS and CXL
Can we use suppressColumnsToolPanel=true as a method, so i can change it when the condition met??
All the solutions that i found, are suggesting to use setColumnVisible, which i'm currently using, but its not working as expected.

This question is similar to: How to hide column in AG-Grid?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
